# Eigen, How to handle element-wise division by zero

Tags: c++, eigen

How to handle an element-wise division in Eigen if some divider could be 0 ?
I would like the result to be 0.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  ArrayXd a(3), b(3), c;
  a << 1, 2, 0;
  b << 1.2, 3.4, 5.6;
  c = b / a;
}
```

Comment: Do you want `1e300 / 1e-300` be infinity but `1e300 / 0.0` to be zero? Or are underflows/overflows ruled out? Do you have positive and negative input values?

Comment: Also, if you are going for speed: What architecture do you support? And how likely are 0 divisors?

Comment: My divider are only positive integer values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle division by zero by using a binaryExpr:

```
ArrayXd a(3), b(3);
a << 1, 2, 0;
b << 1.2, 3.4, 5.6;

Eigen::ArrayXd c = a.binaryExpr(b, [](auto x, auto y) { return y==0 ? 0 : x/y; });
```

Comment: Do you know the efficiency of binaryExpr compared to operator/ ?

Comment: That's basically a a conditional check plus a division. The check is usually quite more efficient than the division, so I'd say, it's basically the same. When you use `/`, I bet Eigen just does the same under the hood.

Comment: Okay tks. It seems logical, I'm confident with your solution

Comment: @MaximeCharrière Note that this will mess up vectorization, a key component in efficient fundamental matrix ops. If high perf is important, there may be better options (preproc, leveraging floating point env if this is for floats, etc), but if you’re more worried about sound semantics, then this approach is one way. Imho a division by zero which is not by design (leveraging fp env) typically indicates a bug, and instead of bug-hiding mechanisms as above, I’d recommend debug asserts for non-zeroness of the denominator matrix prior to the division op.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler is reasonably good with auto-vectorization, you can use the `.select( )` mechanism of Eigen:

```
c = (a!=0).select(b/a, 0.0);
```

Clang 6 or newer (with `-O3 -DNDEBUG -march=skylake`) will compile the main-loop of that to something equivalent to:

```
        vmovupd ymm1, ymmword ptr [rax]
        vcmpneqpd       ymm2, ymm1, ymm0
        vmaskmovpd      ymm3, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rdx]
        vdivpd  ymm1, ymm3, ymm1
        vandpd  ymm1, ymm2, ymm1
        vmovupd ymmword ptr [rax], ymm1
```

The only slight performance improvement would be to avoid the `vmaskmovpd` -- but this is necessary from the compiler's viewpoint, since strictly speaking, `b[i]` is not read for every `i` where `a[i]==0`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution using [binaryExpr](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#aad7622d1bda6a06a575665345edbd564) but not sure it's efficient. Need to test the speed. I have tens of thousands of values to compute.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

template<typename Scalar> 
struct SecureDivisionOp {
  SecureDivisionOp(Scalar v_ = 0) { v = v_; }
  Scalar v;
  Scalar operator()(const Scalar& a, const Scalar& b) const { 
    return b==0 ? v : a/b; 
  }
};

int main()
{
  ArrayXd a(3), b(3), c;
  a << 1, 2, 0;
  b << 1.2, 3.4, 5.6;

  c = b.binaryExpr(a, SecureDivisionOp<double>(0));
  std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Same as my solution. It's as efficient as it gets, I'd say. I'd use a lambda closure instead of your custom class, `[v = 0](auto a, auto b) { return b==0?v:a/b; }`